# DART : how can assign the result of httpRequest on a property object?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I would like to save in a Object property (my_json) a JSON List loaded from an external file. 
With this code my_json properties is always equal to null :{

Thanks in advance for your help :)

```dart
@CustomTag('scaffold-toolsbar-element')
class MyCustomTag extends PolymerElement{

  void click_menu_item(String label) {
    shadowRoot.querySelector('#page_name').text = label;
  }

  MyCustomTag.created() : super.created(){

    var menu_list = new MenuList('menu_items.json');

    addElementToMenu(list_value){
      var newElement = new Element.tag('core-item');
      newElement.setAttribute("icon", list_value["icon"]);
      newElement.setAttribute("label", list_value["label"]);
      newElement.onClick.listen((e) => click_menu_item(list_value["label"]));
      shadowRoot.querySelector('#core_menu_item').children.add(newElement);
    };

    menu_list.my_json.forEach(addElementToMenu);
  }
}

class MenuList {
  String path;
  List my_json;

  MenuList(String path) {
    this.path = path;
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
    httpRequest
    ..open('GET', path)
    ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) => requestComplete(httpRequest))
    ..send('');
  }

  requestComplete(HttpRequest request) {
    // request.status is 200 
    // request.responseText is 
    // "[ {"icon": "settings", "label": "Signin", "main_page": "signin-element"}, {"icon": "home", "label": "About", "main_page": "about-page-element"} ]" 
    if (request.status == 200) {
      this.my_json = JSON.decode(request.responseText);
    }else{
      this.my_json = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my_json is null because the HttpRequest is asynchronous. you try to access my_json before the request is complete.

Comment: You shouldn't do DOM manipulation in the constructor. Use `attached() after the call to `super.attached();`. This has nothing to do with your `my_json` value, just a general advice.

Comment: I updated my answer again - fixed a bug.

Comment: Hi Günter, I think Robert have the point. In chromium if I debug my code or your code an error is trow because menu_list.my_json is null. Just after this error is trowed the debugger enter in requestComplete and assign the json to my_json.

Comment: I think I need to save the json in the local storage and read them.

Comment: @olituks That shouldn't happen anymore with my recent answer. Your solution is the simplest but switching from async to sync by passing a 'true' isn't available in most cases when you call an async method. You should try to become familiar with async. In Dart almost all file or network operations are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MenuList class could look like

```dart
class MenuList {
  String path;
  List my_json;

  static Future<MenuList> create(String path) {
    return new MenuList()._load(path);
  }

  Future<MenuList>_load(String path) {
    Completer completer = new Completer();
    this.path = path;
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
    httpRequest
        ..open('GET', path)
        ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
          requestComplete(httpRequest);
          completer.complete(this);
        })
        ..send('');
    return completer.future;
  }

  requestComplete(HttpRequest request) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      this.my_json = JSON.decode(request.responseText);
    }else{
      this.my_json = null;
    }
  }
}
```

and the constructor of MyCustomTag like

```dart
void attached() {
  super.attached();

  var menu_list;
  MenuList.create('menu_items.json')
  .then((ml) {
    menu_list = ml;
    addElementToMenu(list_value){
      var newElement = new Element.tag('core-item');
      newElement.setAttribute("icon", list_value["icon"]);
      newElement.setAttribute("label", list_value["label"]);
      newElement.onClick.listen((e) => click_menu_item(list_value["label"]));
      shadowRoot.querySelector('#core_menu_item').children.add(newElement);
    };

    menu_list.my_json.forEach(addElementToMenu);
  });
}
```

I haven't actually tested this code but at leas the analyzer was satisfied.

Comment: Can you try HttpRequest.getString() ? It's often easier than open/send/etc

Comment: Yes I already try HttpRequest.getString() and I have the same result.

Comment: Good solution. I add import 'dart:async'; and it's work perfectly well. I think I need to learn Future now :)

Comment: Absolutely - there is now way to escape async execution in Dart. The earlier you become comfortable with it the more fun you will have with Dart. Search for `[dart-async]` here on StackOverflow to find more information.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you require:

```
HttpRequest.request(path, responseType: 'json').then((HttpRequest request) {
  var json = request.response;
});
```

Note that there is a bug in Dartium at the moment:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20129

As a workaround you can omit the responseType parameter and use request.responseText.

Regards, Robert

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks to try help me. I think you have the point. I try to read the property before the HttpRequest is finish because it asynchronous.

Comment: Just use that code - it is much better than getting a text response as it does the json conversion automatically.

I'd suggest using a static method as well that returns a future and returns the object once it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

The solution come from Robert. I try to read an Object property before the JSON List result is assigned to. So I have always a null property...
To avoid that, I add an optional parameter async to my HttpRequest.open like that: ..open('GET', path, **async:false**)

This is the final code.

```dart
@CustomTag('scaffold-toolsbar-element')
class MyCustomTag extends PolymerElement{

  void click_menu_item(String label) {
    shadowRoot.querySelector('#page_name').text = label;
  }

  MyCustomTag.created() : super.created(){

    var menu_list = new MenuList('menu_items.json');

    addElementToMenu(list_value){
      var newElement = new Element.tag('core-item');
      newElement.setAttribute("icon", list_value["icon"]);
      newElement.setAttribute("label", list_value["label"]);
      newElement.onClick.listen((e) => click_menu_item(list_value["label"]));
      shadowRoot.querySelector('#core_menu_item').children.add(newElement);
    };

    menu_list.my_json.forEach(addElementToMenu);
  }
}

class MenuList {
  String path;
  List my_json;

  MenuList(String path) {
    this.path = path;
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
    httpRequest
    ..open('GET', path, async:false)
    ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) => requestComplete(httpRequest))
    ..send('');
  }

  requestComplete(HttpRequest request) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      this.my_json = JSON.decode(request.responseText);
    }else{
      this.my_json = null;
    }
  }
}
```